# what is the difference between http.reqeust and request in node express?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

My code is deployed on UBUNTU Nginx server, admin panel is developed in express js while API is node js, I have following codes in my node express setup -

```
app.get('/admin', isUserAllowed, function(req, res) {
    var optionsuser = {
        'method': 'GET',
        'url': urlapi + 'totalcount', //same code is working with https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1
        'headers': {
            'Cookie': 'refreshToken=54cdc074eba0604dff****'
        }
    };

    request(optionsuser, function(error, responsed) {
        
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
        
        var responsedatad = JSON.parse(responsed.body);
        res.locals = {
            title: 'Dashboard',
            totaldata: responsedatad
        };
        res.render('Dashboard/index');
    });
});
```

Following is my Nginx file -

```
server {
    server_name testdomain.com www.testdomain.com;
    listen PUBLIC_IP_HERE;
    root /home/test/public_html;
    index index.php index.htm index.html;
    
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http: //PUBLIC_IP_HERE:4000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    }

    location /admin {
        proxy_pass http: //localhost:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

I am getting **504 Gateway Time-out** Error. But when I change my Express codes to -

```
app.get('/admin', isUserAllowed, function(req, res) {

    var request = http.request({
        host: 'testdomain.com',
        path: '/api/totalcount',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Cookie': 'refreshToken=54cdc074eba0604dff****',
        }
    }, function(response) {
        // stuff with response data
    });
    request.end();
    res.locals = {
        title: 'Dashboard',
        totaldata: 0
    };
    res.render('Dashboard/index');
});
```

It is working fine, Can anyone please let me know what's the difference between **http.request** and **request**?

My problem is that I have used **request** at so many places so can't update it everywhere.

Thanks much!!

**Update -** When I change

```
var optionsuser = {
        'method': 'GET',
        'url': urlapi + 'totalcount',
        'headers': {
            'Cookie': 'refreshToken=54cdc074eba0604dff****'
        }
    };
```

to

```
var optionsuser = {
        'method': 'GET',
        'url': 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
        'headers': {
            'Cookie': 'refreshToken=54cdc074eba0604dff****'
        }
    };
```

Then it is working fine, please help me.

Comment: [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) is a deprecated 3rd party library. [http.request](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#httprequestoptions-callback) is part of the NodeJS SDK. IMO I wouldn't use either and switch to something modern like [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) or Axios

Comment: Thanks much for your quick response. My codes are working on local.Your comment gave me a hint to check node version at local and server, both are different.

Answer (score 2):

`request()` as you show here:

```
 request(optionsuser, function(error, responsed) { ... });
```

is a third party library from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).  It is a higher level library built on top of `http.request()` and is generally much easier to use than `http.request()` for most things (requires you to write less code).

`http.request()` is built into the nodejs `http` module, but operates at a lower level.  With enough additional code, it can do anything you want.  But, the `request()` library has already written much of that code, making your life easier.

For a variety of reasons, the `request()` library is now **deprecated** and will likely be maintained for a period of time, but is no longer getting new features and is not recommended for new projects.  You can read about that [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142).

There's a list of alternatives to `request()` [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143) which are actively being developed.  This list of alternatives all support promises (the modern way of handling asynchronous operations).  The `request()` library by itself does not support promises.

My personal favorite from that list of alternatives is [got()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) because I like how the API works and its a feature-rich implementation, but other popular libraries in that list are `node-fetch()` and `axios()`.

Here's an example of getting some JSON from a server using `got()`:

```
try {
    const result = await got(someURL).json();
    // use result here
} catch(e) {
    // handle error here
    console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks much for your response, but I am curious to know why the same thing is working if I use place holder API "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1" instead of 'url': urlapi + 'totalcount'

Comment: @ktech - The placeholder API just returns some JSON.  That's all your code appears to be expecting as a response so as long as you give it some JSON, it will still run.  It's not clear what that has to do with your question at all as a URL that returns JSON will work with any of these libraries.

Comment: 'totalcount' API is also returning the JSON data same as Placeholder API does. Strange is that the same codes are working fine at my local system.